# iOS7 UIAlertView EXC_BAD_ACCESS when set UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uialertview

I'm trying to show UIAlertView for iOS 7 device with input field so i have method

```
- (void)createAlertView
{
    NSString *msg = @"Description (optional)";
    UIAlertView *myAlert  = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:lastMarkAsOutdatedActionTitle
                                                   message:msg
                                                  delegate:self
                                         cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                         otherButtonTitles:@"Confirm", nil];
    myAlert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
    [myAlert show];
}
```

which I'm calling like this

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(createAlertView) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

but at the line `myAlert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;` I'm getting error `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x18)`

I created clean project and tested this code - it works so I stucked with it. Any ideas?

**Update**
Screens at the moment of error
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please post the full symbolicated crash log and full error message not just the small part of EXC_BAD_ACCESS. There may be additional information that someone can use to help you.

Comment: There are no crash logs as there are no crash at all. The only thing i can provide are screens at the moment of error.

Comment: If you remove the line, does it still crash?

Comment: No, if line is commented it works. Also it works with UIAlertViewStyleDefault

Comment: Silly question: `UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput ` was only available in iOS 5 onwards. Is your deployment target set to iOS 4 or lower?

Comment: Also, does it work if you use `waitUntilDone:YES`?

Comment: It doesn't work with waitUntilDone:YES;
My deployment target is set to 6.1. I created clean project with deployment target 6.1 and this code works but it doesn't work in my real project.

Comment: Change deployment to iOS 7. IOS 6+ has <4% adoption at this point. Next, try calling the alertView with the text-input code commented-out. Does it still not work?

Comment: @ArtSabintsev Changing deployment target doesn't help me

Comment: I know that much :) I was just giving you some advice. What about commenting out the text-input line of code?

Comment: I've already answered - if line is commented everything works fine.

Comment: Afaik EXC_BAD_ACCESS can happen if an object pointer is deallocated but referenced OR the same object is modified from two different queue. The second screenshot tells me, that the issue happens as an effect after the enum setting, which should be connected to some of the pointers you have in control. From the first screenshot I can see the only two are a title iVar and self. Is it possible that one is either deallocated or modified from same queue?